# how to send multiple parameters to restful webservice

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices

i want to send multiple parameters to restful webservice in salesforce

```
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
            req.setEndpoint('https://end point address');
            req.setMethod('POST');

         /// here i have to pass multiple parameters like this////        
            req.setBody("parameters");
            req.setBody("parameters");
            req.setBody("parameters");
 i want to send few parameters like 

    String id;
    String status;
    String reason;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Http http = new Http();
            req.setTimeout(60000);

            HTTPResponse respns = http.send(req);
            String json= respns.getBody();
```

can i have some suggestions regarding this,sending multiple parameters to webservices

Comment: pls refer the question in my link which has a code sample that passes multiple parameters to the http request Body

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to create a JSON formatted payload (and it looks like you do based on your headers) with multiple key-value pairs, you could construct it like so:

```
String var1 = 'value1';
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeStringField('key1', var1);
gen.writeStringField('key2', 'value2');
gen.writeNumberField('key3', 3);
//etc
gen.writeEndObject();
```

Which yields a payload that looks like:

```
{
"key1" : "value1",
"key2" : "value2",
"key3" : 3,
}
```

And finally, to set your HttpRequest body:

```
req.setBody(gen.getAsString());
```

You should read up on the SFDC JSON and XML generators to really get your head around this.

Comment: Can I post this Json as req. SetBody(json)

Comment: The method signature is setBody(String) not setBody(JSONGenerator). I revised my answer to demonstrate setting your HttpRequest body.